# Audio within region randomly shifting out of sync in Logic Pro X

Tags: logic-pro, podcasts

I've been editing a podcast in Logic Pro X and a really odd thing happened where I was trimming regions and then putting them together, and while the regions are cut where I cut them, the audio within them has shifted anywhere from 1-20 seconds off. I have two tracks and both tracks are technically in sync but the position of the audio is all off from where I trimmed it.

Has anyone experienced this before and/or knows how to fix?

I've been using trim and shuffle left mainly, and did apply a cross fade to all the regions at some point.

Answer (score -1):

This to me sounds like a typical Logic bug, but I can't be sure. Years ago in Logic Pro 8 I found a bug where if you soloed a track then moved a clip on that track before unsoloing it, it rendered the entire project with the track unable to come out of solo status. It was a catastrophic bug and put me off Logic for life. Pro Tools is known for its bugs but it's never had catastrophic ones. Sorry I can't be more helpful.